# Where does Stannis's army come from in S04E10?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the last episode of [*Game of Thrones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/) season 4, Stannis's army comes and kills the wildings. It's great but which path did they take to go behind the wall?

The wildings want to go to the other side of the wall, if there is an easier way than go through Castle Black, why don't they take it?

Comment: Seems like they could just swim or canoe around eastwatch, the wall's not that wide...

Comment: I get how they got there, but not having read the books I'm not at all sure why they were there?

Comment: Of course the wildlings could sail around the wall, if east watch wasn't manned and if they had built boats. The wall was not put up to stop wildlings going south or anyone else going north, but to stop what else(white walkers)lay North of the wall going south. The episodes in season 4 do not really explain how stannis got there, especially as he was at the iron bank only a few episodes earlier.

Comment: From left, right and center!

Comment: This has now been [asked on Scifi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86194/how-did-stanniss-army-get-north-of-the-wall) as well

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Good question! I'm not entirely sure how it's portrayed in the final episode, but to take knowledge from the books, he simply sailed north of the wall and his army marched from there. The wall extends across the entire land, but it's certainly possible to sail north or south of it.

According to the books, the orange arrow is where he landed:

[image]

He leaves some of his men at Eastwatch and marches the rest westward to Castle Black.

Comment: Ok, it makes more sense for me. Thanks ! (sorry i can't upvote your response, i don't have enough reputation)

Comment: To clarify, the wildlings don't have enough big boats to sneak past by sea

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, the wall isn't there against the wildlings, is it?

Comment: what about the Gorge area?? there is no wall from The Frostfangs side ?

Comment: @roottraveller there is no "Wall" there because it is so mountainous it's basically impassible.